# Selecting sepecific value from json string in postgres

Tags: java, sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am working on a data structure which is stored in form of JSON string in database. I am using postgres database.
I have a table named usersettings. There are two columns in it.
One column is id(primary key and auto incremented) and other one is settings(type text).

The settings column contains data in JSON format(See example below)

```
{
   "SUBJECTS":[
      "Maths","Physics"
   ],
   "NAME":[
      "Thomas"
   ],
   "EMAIL_ADDRESS":"abc@xyz.com",
   "CITY":[
      "Newyork"
   ],
   "USER_ID":3,
   "TYPE":[
      "Secondary"
   ]
}
```

Here, the json data contains json array. I need a select sql query using which i can fetch only those rows which contains specific USER_ID(in the above example it is 3) and whose subjects contains Maths.

Comment: You are out of luck as the [un-supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) Postgres version 9.1 did not have any JSON support at all. Parsing JSON without any built-in functions will be a nightmare. Before you continue, upgrade to a recent Postgres version (12, 13)

Comment: In addition to upgrading to a newer version of postgres, you should also make sure to use the jsonb type. `jsonb` supports many operations that `json` does not.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have upgraded to Postgres version (12, 13), you can use a recursive CTE that flattens out the JSON structures for each row, associating the user id for each row's settings with every item in the array for the "subjects" key. Then, a subquery with `exists` can be used to find the user ids that have "Maths" as a subject:

```
with recursive cte(uid, js, subject, sid) as (
    select u.settings::json -> 'USER_ID', u.settings, (u.settings::json -> 'SUBJECTS')::json ->> 0, 1 from usersettings u
    union all
    select c.uid, c.js, (c.js::json -> 'SUBJECTS'):: json ->> c.sid, c.sid+1 from cte c where c.sid < json_array_length(c.js::json -> 'SUBJECTS')
),
results(id, subject) as (select uid::TEXT, subject from cte)
select distinct r1.id from results r1 where exists (select 1 from results r2 where r2.id = r1.id and r2.subject = 'Maths');
```

Output:

| id |
| --- |
| 3 |

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9b38d11bdc820cd5941704b254848c2f).